# Can't read first row of CSV file

Tags: csv, vbscript, imacros

I can't figure out why my script is not reading and storing the first row of the CSV file.  It is starting with the second row for some reason.

I have the following code (reading from a 2 column CSV file):

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")

'this just gets the folder where the csv file lives
sDir = GetiMacrosFolder("DataSources")

strConnect = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
             "DefaultDir=" & sDir & ";"

rs.Open "select * from test.csv", strConnect

count = 0

Do Until rs.EOR
    ReDim Preserve var1(count)
    var1(count) = rs.fields(0)

    ReDim Preserve var2(count)
    var2(count) = rs.fields(1)

    count = count + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
```

If I then do a `MsgBox(var1(1))`, it shows me the value in row 3 and not row 2 like it should.

Comment: @AnsgarWichers answer is correct - if the file doesn't have headers, you can use the Jet driver instead.  See [these](https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/) example connection strings.

Comment: Use Jet with `HDR=Yes;`, see @Comintern link.

Comment: @omegastripes You mean `HDR=No;`.

Comment: @AnsgarWichers you are right of course, I see you've shown.

Comment: Just a tip... your recordset loop could be completely eliminated by just using the `GetRows()` function. `rs.Open "select col1,col2 from test.csv", strConnect : a = rs.GetRows()`. Now you have a two-dimensional array. `a(0, x)` contains the col1 values. `a(1, x)` contains the col2 values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Bond, I'll play around with your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Recordset` object reads the first line of the CSV as the table headers, so the second line is the first data row. You can avoid this by using a driver that you can instruct not to do that:

```vb
strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sDir & _
             ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
```

or by placing a [`schema.ini`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx) like this alongside the CSV:

```
[test.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=False
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=ANSI
```

Note that `CSVDelimited` only works when your file is actually comma-separated *and* you have the comma defined as the field separator character in your system's regional settings. Otherwise you need to specify your delimiter character in that file:

```
[test.csv]
Format=Delimited(<delimiter>)
ColNameHeader=False
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=ANSI
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all the info and example!  I'll give this a try.

Comment: Well, I was actually going to accept your answer when it was just the first sentence of "The Recordset object reads the first line of the CSV as the table headers, so the second line is the first data row."  Really, that answers my question.  I was wondering why my code was reading from row 2 and you told me why (backed up by a couple other people's comments).  That's why I accepted the answer.  The rest was just additional help you offered to me.  I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: Just tried your new connection string suggestion.  Worked perfect!  Thanks again.